# Searching the Catastral in the Canary Islands

Tags: spain

Is there a way to search the Catastral in the Canary Islands for a Surname or Company name to find the address of that person?

Comment: http://visor.grafcan.es/visorweb/ allows you to search a word but it appears to not search personal ownership but businesses, street names, neighborhoods, schools, etc. (points of interest). I wouldn't expect that kind of detail to be shown/allowed because of privacy issues.

Comment: Many thanks for that, I will check it out, any information is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In https://www.grafcan.es/2010/09/idecanarias-en-la-sede-electronica-del-catastro they talk about the [Catastro from the Spanish government](http://www.sedecatastro.gob.es/).

From there you can check [*Consulta de Datos Catastrales. Referencia Catastral*](https://www1.sedecatastro.gob.es/OVCFrames.aspx?TIPO=CONSULTA), that is, Check Cadastral Data. Cadastral reference.

In that specific search box you can look for the cadastre reference of a given address, but not the contrary: given a name, you cannot get the address. This is explained in the [FAQs from the Dirección general del catastro](http://www.catastro.minhap.gob.es/esp/faqs.asp):

> **IV. Acceso a la información catastral**
>   **¿Es posible acceder a toda la información catastral de un inmueble? ¿Cómo?**
>
> Cualquier persona puede acceder a la información catastral que no contenga datos protegidos: localización del inmueble, referencia catastral, superficie, uso o destino, clase de cultivo o aprovechamiento, calidad de la construcción o cartografía.
>
> Solo el titular catastral y las personas o entidades autorizadas pueden acceder a los datos protegidos, que son:
>
> - El nombre, apellidos, razón social, código de identificación y domicilio de quienes figuren inscritos en el Catastro como titulares.
> - El valor catastral y los valores catastrales del suelo y, en su caso, de la construcción, de cada inmueble individualizado.

Basically, it says that cadastral information such as full name and identifiable information, as well as its price, is just available to the owner and authorized people.